# Proof: At most 3 circles of radius 1/2 fit into the interior of a halfcircle of radius 1

Tags: circles, packing-problem

It is a well known fact that at most 7 interior disjoint circles of radius 1/2 can be centered in a circle of radius 1; note that they don't need to be fully contained in the radius 1 circle.

I am interested in a simple proof idea to show that at most 3 interior disjoint circles of radius 1/2 can be centered in the **interior** of a halfcircle of radius 1.

While intuitively clear, I am lacking an idea as how to approach the proof and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: If you're assuming the first truth, and if four could fit into a half circle, how much would fit in a whole circle?

Comment: @David Peterson, Thank you for your comment. I was thinking of a proof only involving "fundamental" geometrical facts, i.e., a self-contained proof

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding "interior" but to me it is not a well known fact that $6$ interior disjoint circles of radius $1/2$ can be centered in a circle of radius $1$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle

Comment: @Henry Sorry for the confusion. 6 interior disjoint circles of radius 1/2 can __not__ be centered in a circle of radius 1, but can if not restricted to the interior. I am on the otherhand indeed interested in the restriction of halfcircle and interior. The 6 circle part was just to provide some context.

Comment: What makes a circle "interior"? Does the circle have to be entirely in the bigger circle, or just its centre with part of the smaller circle being outside the bigger circle?

Comment: @Henry By the interior I meant the region inside the circle, so all points with distance less than the radius. And yes, the small circles do not need to be fully contained in the big circle, but their centers need to be, in the interior

Comment: Ah, that is a more interesting problem. You might want to edit the original question to reflect what exactly you mean. I think given the comments most people are assuming you meant usual packing where the entire circle needs be contained.